# How to I tell when a thread is complete?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a method that can take time to complete as it uses the internet to check something and depending on the internet speeds can take a while so I have placed it into its own thread but I'm wanting to know how I can notice when this thread is complete as I then need to update the screen from the Main thread.

```
New thread code looks like this:
Thread newThread = new Thread(){
             @Override
                public void run() {

//My thread code
};
    newThread.start();
```

This is what the thread code looks like, not going to copy and paste all the code it uses as it would be pointless but I'm wanting something like when

```
newThread.iscomplete {
//More code
}
```

Something along those lines

Thanks

Comment: Why not simply update the screen from the spawned thread, when it has the result? Or pass a callback object to the spawned thread that will be called by it when it ends?

Comment: If you want to do something at the end of a thread, you can add it to the code it runs at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can show a message at the end of the Thread. Which would be helpful to let the user know that the process has finished.

#### Showing Message

```
System.out.print("Thread has finished!");
```

This would be at the last line, so it would only execute if all the above codes have been executed and the code has reached the last line for execution.

```
Thread newThread = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //My Thread code
        System.out.print("Done!");
    }
};
```

This will print **Done!** in the Console (I assume application is being run using a Console). Denoting that the code has been executed.

#### using a variable

```
boolean done = false;
Thread newThread = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //My Thread code
        done = true;
    }
};
```

#### Using EventListeners

Or else you can use Event Listener to detect the Thread completion. The above method was kind of simple.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/

Comment: How can the rest of his code tell that?

Comment: @AnubianNoob, I have editted my answer...

Comment: The second one won't compile. Try it out. Also the answer is a duplicate and has already been answered, your efforts would be better spent elsewhere.